# How can I automate data frame manipulation subbing in whatever team name input I have to return the manipulated version of that data? Rstudio

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to automate a bunch of data frame manipulations based on an input where it returns a one row dataframe called (team name input)stuff2022c. I will eventually turn this into a dataset for all teams in 2022 and possibly more seasons, which I would then just edit the function slightly to fix that. I am using R Studio.

```
datacleanup <- function(team){

##the teamcap2022 dataset is scraped and already named with (actual team name)cap2022
teamcap2022$Player <- gsub(" .*", "",  teamcap$Player) 
teamcap2022$Player <- gsub("\n\t\t\t\n", "", teamcap$Player)
teamcap2022$average <- gsub(",", "",  teamcap$average) 
teamcap2022$average <- gsub("\\$", "",  teamcap$average)
teamcap2022 <- subset(teamcap, select = c("Player", "POS", "average") )
teamcap2022$average <- as.numeric(teamcap$average)

teamcap2022 <- teamcap2022 %>%
  na.omit(teamcap2022) %>%
   mutate(posg = case_when(
     POS %in% c("T", "G", "C", "RT", "LT", "RG", "LG") ~ "OL",
     POS %in% c("QB") ~ "QB",
     POS %in% c("RB") ~ "RB",
     POS %in% c("WR") ~ "WR",
     POS %in% c("TE", "FB") ~ "TE",
     POS %in% c("K", "P", "LS") ~ "ST",
     POS %in% c("OLB", "ILB", "LB", "DE", "DT") ~ "Front7",
     POS %in% c("CB", "S", "DB", "FS", "SS", "NCB", "SAF") ~ "DB",
     TRUE ~ "Other"
            ),
     
          )
teamcap2022 <- teamcap2022 %>%
  group_by(posg) %>%
  mutate(cash = sum(average),
            nump = n()) %>%
  select(-c("POS", "average", "Player"))

teamcap2022 <- teamcap2022 %>%
  mutate(cap_pct = percent(cash/sum(cash)))




##the teampicks2022 for each team is already created outside this function already named with (actual team name)cap2022


teampicks2022 <- teampicks2022[c("pick", "posg")]
teampicks2022 <- teampicks2022 %>%
  left_join(thevaluechart, by = "pick") %>%
  mutate(
    top100 = case_when(
      pick < 101 ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
    ),
    latepicks = case_when( 
      pick > 100 ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
      )
  )




teampicks2022 <- teampicks2022 %>%
  group_by(posg) %>%
  summarize(
    top100 = sum(top100),
    latepicks = sum(latepicks),
    value = sum(value),
    
    .groups = 'drop'
  ) %>%
mutate(value_pct = percent(value/sum(value)))

team2022stuff <- teamcap2022 %>%
  left_join(teampicks2022, by = "posg")
  
  team2022stuffc <- team2022stuff %>%
  mutate(
    top100_QB = ifelse(posg == "QB", top100, NA),
    top100_RB = ifelse(posg == "RB", top100, NA),
    top100_WR = ifelse(posg == "WR", top100, NA),
    top100_OL = ifelse(posg == "OL", top100, NA),
    top100_TE = ifelse(posg == "TE", top100, NA),
    top100_ST = ifelse(posg == "ST", top100, NA),
    top100_DB = ifelse(posg == "DB", top100, NA),
    top100_Front7 = ifelse(posg == "Front7", top100, NA),
    latepicks_QB = ifelse(posg == "QB", latepicks, NA),
    latepicks_RB = ifelse(posg == "RB", latepicks, NA),
    latepicks_WR = ifelse(posg == "WR", latepicks, NA),
    latepicks_OL = ifelse(posg == "OL", latepicks, NA),
    latepicks_TE = ifelse(posg == "TE", latepicks, NA),
    latepicks_ST = ifelse(posg == "ST", latepicks, NA),
    latepicks_DB = ifelse(posg == "DB", latepicks, NA),
    latepicks_Front7 = ifelse(posg == "Front7", latepicks, NA),
    value_QB = ifelse(posg == "QB", value, NA),
    value_RB = ifelse(posg == "RB", value, NA),
    value_WR = ifelse(posg == "WR", value, NA),
    value_OL = ifelse(posg == "OL", value, NA),
    value_TE = ifelse(posg == "TE", value, NA),
    value_ST = ifelse(posg == "ST", value, NA),
    value_DB = ifelse(posg == "DB", value, NA),
    value_Front7 = ifelse(posg == "Front7", value, NA),
    cash_QB = ifelse(posg == "QB", cash, NA),
    cash_RB = ifelse(posg == "RB", cash, NA),
    cash_WR = ifelse(posg == "WR", cash, NA),
    cash_OL = ifelse(posg == "OL", cash, NA),
    cash_TE = ifelse(posg == "TE", cash, NA),
    cash_ST = ifelse(posg == "ST", cash, NA),
    cash_DB = ifelse(posg == "DB", cash, NA),
    cash_Front7 = ifelse(posg == "Front7", cash, NA),
    nump_QB = ifelse(posg == "QB", nump, NA),
    nump_RB = ifelse(posg == "RB", nump, NA),
    nump_WR = ifelse(posg == "WR", nump, NA),
    nump_OL = ifelse(posg == "OL", nump, NA),
    nump_TE = ifelse(posg == "TE", nump, NA),
    nump_ST = ifelse(posg == "ST", nump, NA),
    nump_DB = ifelse(posg == "DB", nump, NA),
    nump_Front7 = ifelse(posg == "Front7", nump, NA),
    cap_pct_QB = ifelse(posg == "QB", cap_pct, NA),
    cap_pct_RB = ifelse(posg == "RB", cap_pct, NA),
    cap_pct_WR = ifelse(posg == "WR", cap_pct, NA),
    cap_pct_OL = ifelse(posg == "OL", cap_pct, NA),
    cap_pct_TE = ifelse(posg == "TE", cap_pct, NA),
    cap_pct_ST = ifelse(posg == "ST", cap_pct, NA),
    cap_pct_DB = ifelse(posg == "DB", cap_pct, NA),
    cap_pct_Front7 = ifelse(posg == "Front7", cap_pct, NA),
    value_pct_QB = ifelse(posg == "QB", value_pct, NA),
    value_pct_RB = ifelse(posg == "RB", value_pct, NA),
    value_pct_WR = ifelse(posg == "WR", value_pct, NA),
    value_pct_OL = ifelse(posg == "OL", value_pct, NA),
    value_pct_TE = ifelse(posg == "TE", value_pct, NA),
    value_pct_ST = ifelse(posg == "ST", value_pct, NA),
    value_pct_DB = ifelse(posg == "DB", value_pct, NA),
    value_pct_Front7 = ifelse(posg == "Front7", cap_pct, NA)
  ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-c("value", "top100", "latepicks", "posg", "cap_pct", "nump", "cash")) %>%
    summarise(
    across(starts_with("top100"), ~ last(na.omit(.))),
    across(starts_with("latepicks"), ~ last(na.omit(.))),
    across(starts_with("cash"), ~ last(na.omit(.))),
    across(starts_with("cap_pct"), ~ last(na.omit(.))),
    across(starts_with("nump"), ~ last(na.omit(.))),
    across(starts_with("value"), ~ last(na.omit(.)))
  ) %>%
  mutate_all(~ ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .))

}
```

I get Error in datacleanup(cardinals) : object 'teamcap' not found.

I have tried some versions of turning it to text to gsub then rerunning the function and I haven't had success. Any help on this matter would be extremely appreciated and I would be happy to share any results with anyone who wanted it there after.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Sadly, at the moment, your question is neither minimal nor reproducible.

Comment: At no point you are creating a data frame called `teamcap` hence the error.